# Is it possible to run webkit on OSX?

Tags: osx

the latest version of emacs embedded with xwidget browser

you can run `xwidget-webkit-browse-url` to use it

I try the command many times
  and install the gtk from homebrew on my MacBook

finally the error message appeared,
   which I still can't remove until now

```
Your Emacs was not compiled with xwidgets support
```

Comment: Presumably the error message is telling the truth. If you want xwidgets support you will need to recompile emacs. If you do this I guess you will find that you to install certain libraries that you don't have. This is all relatively straightforward on Linux, but I have no experience of OSX.

Comment: I have tried to recompile emacs on my MacBook, it is said my gtk is not provided, but I have already installed, there is also not enough information about this topic, expecting someone can work it out and share it for us

Comment: You might want to try this experimental repository [veshboo/emacs][1].
I can compile and run it without problems on my MacBook air.
[1]:https://github.com/veshboo/emacs